# Can i use ng-model with <p> tag?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular-js and i think this is a basic question how to get the value from a paragraph tag in angular-js? I tried with using ng-model but doesn't giving the value.Can anyone help me?

Comment: That should have worked, Can you put your code here?  http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:3510140

Comment: edit your code in question...

Comment: Check whether you are setting ng-app properly in your view (html). It should be the same name as you give name for your app.module.

Comment: @KishorPawar : can you please go through this link. http://plnkr.co/edit/1xLOmU2PEeic6FWTgeAw?p=preview  this is what i tried.

Comment: your plunker is working

Comment: have you seen the alert.I am alerting the content in the <p> tag. but it doesn't shows the content.

Comment: it shows http://plnkr.co/edit/2JkfN5yNBQ8loi3g8U6t?p=preview

Answer (score 8):

`ng-model` is working for two way binding. p tag is not supported for `ng-model`. if you want to bind p tag then you can use `ng-bind` or `{{}}`.

```
<p ng-bind="test"></p>
```

[plunker code here with ng-bind](http://plnkr.co/edit/lxUN6WM9D7VNbUZpYxAS?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

No. You can not use `ng-model` for `<p>` tag. If you want to show the value of scope variable inside `<p>` tag, Then you can use expressions.

Example

```
 <p> {{ variable }} </p>
```

This will show the value of `variable` into paragraph.

Comment: ng-model can be used for <p> tag, I can show whatever is there in model variable in <p> tag

Comment: @KishorPawar By default ng-model works only with inputs until you write your own directive to handle it. Do some research before downvoting

Answer (score 0):

You can only directly mutate that ng-model in the controller to which the view is binded via an input tag. You could use {{}} or ng-bind for one way binding, from controller to view. But to achieve two way data binding you need an input tag or other alternatives like select.

In your case if you want to read changes inside other tags like p tags you need to watch those tags inside the scope, using $scope.$watch and listen for updates have a callback function execute on change.

So basically you can't achieve what your trying to do here. This is because p tags have static values and they do not change, so one way data binding is the best option here, from controller to view during the initialization of that tag. No point, later, would you be able to change the value inside the p tag, thus no need for two data binding here. Thus ng-model is not supported. Only ng-bind or {{}}.

Answer (score 0):

Ng-model is not supported for P,H tags,,,

if you want to bind tags then use ng-class

`<p ng-class="localUser.yourdata">{{localUser.yourdata}}</p>`

`<h1 ng-class="localUser.yourdata">{{localUser.yourdata}}</h1>`

hope this is help full