# Cannot read property at Object.eval?

Tags: angular

In my project, I have functionality like on click particular product I want to show product particular detail, here I take `product: Object = [];` as an object.In my constructor

```
constructor( private _productService: UserService,
           private _router: Router,
           private _avRoute: ActivatedRoute,
           private _actRouter: ActivatedRoute) {
              if (this._avRoute.snapshot.params["id"]) {
                this.Productid = parseInt(this._avRoute.snapshot.params["id"]);
                console.log(this.Productid);
              }
              else {

              }
           }
```

in which i get an id of the particular product, in my `ngOninit()`

```
ngOnInit() {
if (this.Productid > 0) {
  this._productService.productDetail(this.Productid)
    .subscribe( data => { this.product = data },
    error => {
      debugger;
      this.errorMessage = error;
    }
  )
}
```

So my question is that when i bind with my html control ,

```
<div id="mainImage">
       <img [src]="data.ProductImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="box"> 
      <h1 class="text-center" >{{data.ProductName}}</h1>
      <p class="goToDescription"><a href="#details" class="scroll-to" >{{data.ProductShortDesc}}</a>
</div>
```

when i bind with this it's get error like `Cannot read property 'ProductImage' of undefined
    at Object.eval`
I refer this site to query but not work [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969785/can-i-use-ng-model-with-p-tag)

Comment: Instead of data.productImage in the html control, it should be product.productImage.

Comment: @NiralMunjariya i used like as you said, but not worked.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer Please help i will try all the way.

Comment: Have you console.log the data that you're getting from the service?

Comment: @NiralMunjariya ya do console.log i will get ,Array(1)
0
:
{$id: "1", ProductId: 4, ProductName: "T-Shirt", ProductPrice: 45, ProductCartDesc: "This is Men Shopping", …}
length
:
1

Comment: Please have a look at the answer that I've added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with use of `ngFor` loop,

```
<div *ngFor="let item of product">
   <div id="mainImage">
     <img [src]="item .ProductImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
   </div>
   <div class="box"> 
     <h1 class="text-center" >{{item .ProductName}}</h1>
     <p class="goToDescription"><a href="#details" class="scroll-to" >
     {{item .ProductShortDesc}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Vivek Doshi can it is the correct way to do this? I got output, exactly same as I want

Comment: you're getting an array from the server side either you can do product = data[0] or you'll have to use for loop to access the property of product object.

Comment: @BrijeshMavani , if you are getting only one product details then don't use ngFor , instead use `this.product = data[0];` and follow one of my way

Answer (score 0):

First change `data` to `product` and then you can go for 2 approach :

**1. Use ngIf to check product data is available or not**

```
<div *ngIf="product">
    <div id="mainImage">
        <img [src]="product.ProductImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="box"> 
        <h1 class="text-center" >{{product.ProductName}}</h1>
        <p class="goToDescription"><a href="#details" class="scroll-to" >{{product.ProductShortDesc}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**2. use safe operator ?**

```
<div id="mainImage">
    <img [src]="product?.ProductImage" alt="" class="img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="box"> 
    <h1 class="text-center" >{{product?.ProductName}}</h1>
    <p class="goToDescription"><a href="#details" class="scroll-to" >{{product?.ProductShortDesc}}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I change data to product

Comment: i stuck for last 4 hours ,please help

Comment: @BrijeshMavani , sorry was not on my desk , will you please a demo for the same , so I can help you quickly ?

Answer (score 0):

code for product detail component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from './service/user.service.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-detail',
  templateUrl: './product-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-detail.component.scss']
})
export class ProductDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedId: any = 0;
  product: any;
  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private _productService: UserService) {
    this.activatedRoute.pathFromRoot.forEach((path: ActivatedRoute) => {
      if (path.snapshot.params && path.snapshot.params['id']) {
        this.selectedId = Number(path.snapshot.params['id']);
        this._productService.productDetail(this.selectedId)
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.product = data[0];
        });
      };
    });
  }
}
```

In html,

```
<pre> {{product | json}} </pre>
```

Please try this and check is there any data coming in the product object or not.

Comment: with *ngFor it's worked, but with your code, i am working on